# In node.js, how do I convert an err.code like ETIMEDOUT to a more readable string?

Tags: node.js

In Node.js, is there a strerror() method or module available to convert codes like ETIMEDOUT, EACCESS, etc to more human-readable string? ("Connection timed out", "Permission denied", etc).

If it helps or is relevant, in one case I'm using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) similarly to the following:

```
    request.get(myurl, function(err, response, body) {
      if (err) return cb(err);
      ...
```

and the non-linuxy users of my code don't particularly like the `{"code":"ETIMEDOUT"}` or other cryptic error codes I end up printing out for them.

I'm about to write something to convert those codes to strings after dumping out /usr/include/asm*/errno* but I'm more inclined to believe I'm missing something than no one else has already figured this out. Thanks!

Comment: just curious, does the err object have anything other than just the code?  I'm guessing not, but thought I'd ask.

Comment: good question, I poked around, it seems to vary. For child_process.exec, there's a lot more (e.g. stack, message), but for request, no just code.

Answer (score 0):

Was just dealing with this the other day! I handled it via assert.ifError(err, "Timed out!");

Comment: It might not just be timed out, it could also be connection refused, and probably others too.

Answer (score 0):

The "constants" module is available if you want an object with properties that match the code (constant) and map to an even more cryptic integer!

```
var c = require('constants');
console.log(c.ETIMEDOUT); //60
```

Comment: That's funny. And it's platform-specific too :-).